# How to recover whole HDD after format twice?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

Accidently formatted hard disk, then saved some files and again formatted, But now using icare, cant find the previous formatted files.

Comment: You didn't learn your lesson the first time?  You should not expect to recover anything after formatting a drive -- anything you get is "gravy".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what an "icare" is. But to answer your question:

- If you have overwritten areas of the drive that used to contain the data you want, then the answer is no, you cannot recover that data.
- If the areas of the drive have not been overwritten, the answer is yes, you can recover that data.

Since we don't do software recommendations, I suggest you have a look on Google or Bing, and find some software that has a good record for data recovery.

Failing that, look at paying someone to recover your data.

Comment: Recommending software in the course of an answer is fine, if done properly (and [as long as the question is not just asking for software recommendations](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software): http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend www.lowcostrecovery.com for great service and reasonable prices.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very very hard to recover files that have been overwritten, formatting is not that bad, but not overwriting...

Ok, I know what **iCare** is, but I still recommend "[easeUS Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-software/)". It helped me, BUT I didn't format it 2 times and overwrite it...
You can try if you want. For my HDD, it took **3 hours** to scan( I know it's long...)

If you're not sure if the software can recover your files, download the free version, it will allow you to just scan(But not recover, unless you but the paid one)
And I **don't recommend** any pirated apps, cause they might contain stuff you wouldn't want.